# App is crashing with NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm try to open en new screen after the nstimer and i'm using:

```
MultiplayerController* controller = [[MultiplayerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MultiplayerController" bundle:nil];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller.playeronecount setText:playeronecount.text];
```

But the app is giving me a SIGABRT.

in the .h file;

```
IBOutlet UILabel *playeronecount;  

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *playeronecount;
```

> 2012-01-12 21:56:16.016 [9621:707] -[MultiplayerController
>   playeronecount]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x39824a0
>   2012-01-12 21:56:16.020 [9621:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MultiplayerController playeronecount]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x39824a0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x33ff48bf 0x357101e5 0x33ff7acb 0x33ff6945 0x33f51680 0x5f85 0x31ac361d 0x33fc8a63 0x33fc86c9
>   0x33fc729f 0x33f4a4dd 0x33f4a3a5 0x35b8afcd 0x3508f743 0x275f 0x2704)
>   terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)

Comment: You have not provided enough context to debug this issue. Please post the surrounding code including the timer. Also post any errors or exceptions that are being thrown.

Comment: Did you remember to @synthesize `playeronecount` in MultiplayerController.m?

Comment: I edited the post. It's not the timer when i put the last line in command it worked. ->  [controller.playeronecount setText:playeronecount.text];

Comment: Is that the code from the MultiplayerController?

Comment: @MarkAdams ; Pff thank you! Post it as a answer and i wil accept it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `@synthesize` `playeronecount` in order to generate the getter and setter methods, `-playeronecount` and `-setplayeronecount` respectively. Attempting to access a property without these methods synthesized will result in an "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" exception.